Frequent 503 errors on Microsoft Graph API calendarView/delta endpoint when fetching large date ranges
We have a Node.js service that uses the Microsoft Graph API. Specifically, we use the users/:user/calendarview/delta endpoint to track changes in the calendar of a meeting room. Our query covers a date range from now minus 180 days to now plus 1 year.
The service has been working perfectly in production since 2022.
However, starting from 24/10/2024, for some meeting rooms, the API frequently returns a 503 Service Unavailable error when we paginate through the results of calendarView/delta.
We have attempted retries with 30-second intervals and adjusted the page size, but the issue persists.
Interestingly, if we reduce the date range significantly, it seems to work after a while. However, the query fails once the range extends to about 5 or 6 months from the current date, which doesn’t meet our needs.
We couldn’t find any updates to this API in the documentation, nor any communication about ongoing issues.
Has anyone encountered similar problems, or could suggest a workaround? Any help is appreciated!
